# How to pass React Component as props to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call PopupDialog.tsx inside Content.tsx as a sibling of Item.tsx. 
Previously PopupDialog.tsx is called inside C.tsx file but due to z index issue i am trying to bring it out and call it in Content.tsx

Is it possible to somehow pass the whole component(popupDialog and its parameters) in Content.tsx so that i could avoid passing back and forth the parameters needed for popupdialog in content.tsx.

Code in C.tsx where PopupDialog component is called.

```
const C = (props: Props) => (
  <>
      {props.additionalInfo ? (
      <div className="infoButton">
        <PopupDialog   // need to take this code out and want to add in Content.tsx 
          icon="info"
          callback={props.callback}
          position={Position.Right}
        >
          <div className="popuplist">{props.additionalInfo}</div>
        </PopupDialog>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <Button className="iconbutton"/>
    )}
  </>
);
```

Content.tsx where i would like to call PopupDialog.tsx with its parameters

```
const Content = (props: Props) => {
  const [componentToRender, docomponentToRender] = React.useState(null);
  const [isAnimDone, doAnim] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="ContentItems">
      <PWheel agent={props.agent} />
      {isAnimDone && (
        <>
          <Item {props.agent} />
          {componentToRender &&
            <PopupDialog/>     //want to call here with all its parameters to be passed
          }
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Folder Structure

```
App.tsx
 ->ViewPort.tsx
   ->Content.tsx
     ->PWheel.tsx
     ->Item.tsx
       ->A.tsx
         ->B.tsx
           ->C.tsx
            {props.additionalinfo &&
              ->PopupDialog.tsx
     ->PopupDialog.tsx
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you might want to consider using React Portals for your popup dialogs to avoid having to deal with positioning it relative to the calling components.  https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand the question correctly you want to pass one component into another so that you can use the properties or data of the passed componenet in your current component.
So there are three ways to achieve this.

1)Sending the data or entire component as prop.This brings disadvantage that even though components which don't require knowledge
about the passed component will also have to ask as a prop.So this is bascially prop drilling.

2)The other is you can use context api.So context api is a way to maintain global state variale.so if you follow this approach you don't need to pass data or componenet as props.Wherever you need the data you can inport context object and use it in componenet.

3)Using Redux library.This is similar to context api but only disadavantage is that we will have to write lot of code to implement this.Redux is a javascript library.

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Adding to list of @CodeOfLife 
4) We can use RxJs too for maintaining the Application state, RxJs is a JS library for reactive programming.

Answer (score 0):

You need to :

```
  <>
          <Item {props.agent} />
          {componentToRender &&
            <PopupDialog abc={componentToRender} /> //you must call in this component, in this case i name it is abc , i pass componentToRender state to it
          }
        </>
```

and then PopupDialog will  receive componentToRender as abc, in PopupDialog , you just need to call `props.abc` and done .

- If you need to know more about prop and component you can see it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is **Higher-Order-Components (HOC).**

The basic usage is:

```
const EnhancedComponent = higherOrderComponent(WrappedComponent);
```

Below is such an implementation that takes a component (with all its props) as a parameter:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const Content = WrappedComponent => {
  return class Content extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <>
          {/* Your Content component comes here */}
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        </>
      );
    }
  };
};

export default Content;
```

Here is the link for higher-order-components on React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Answer (score 0):

Make use of

```
useContext()
```

Follow this for details: 
[React Use Context Hook](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usecontext-hook)